# How to force a cursor globally in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, cursor

How can I set a particular cursor (for example, the normal everyday pointer) and have it not get changed to fingers, loading spinners, hourglasses, or cutesy sprites?

I've tried writing a console application which sets an override property, but it has no global effect.  I've tried Windows settings...  I simply want every application no matter what (as long as they use a system-provided mouse api) to use one cursor forever.

Answer (score 0):

lol you just can use another cursor in windows or programs that use the windows cursor. to not change it on any circumstance, get into your mouse options, cursor options, and pick standard cursor on everything (beam, pen, no, size etc.)

even tough, if this is what you want, i can not recommend it. having no indicator what is happening sucks hard, and not having another cursor for sizing and stuff cripples your interactions with your pc. but nvm, do what you think is good for you.

Comment: My issue is not with a Windows system cursor, but with application cursors which override my Windows system cursor.  I'm basically looking for a way to disable cursor appearance modification from what I set by any means (other than something like a directx drawn cursor of course).  Don't downvote if you don't understand the question...  Ask for clarification instead.